# Plot an arrow going through a chosen point with FancyArrowPatch

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to find a way to plot an arrow going through a point I have chosen beforehand, and I'd like to be able to set freely the tail width and the color of this arrow.

I went and looked up at the FancyArrowPatch library from matplotlib, which I'm already using to plot arrows going from a point to another. However, I can't use it in a satisfying way.

For example, i'm trying in the following code to plot an arrow, going from (-10,0) to (0,9) and going through (-5,9).

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.patches as mpatch
import matplotlib.path as mpath


style = "simple,tail_width=10,head_width=30,head_length=60"
kw = dict(arrowstyle=style,color="#49107C")
Arrow = mpatch.FancyArrowPatch(path=mpath.Path([(-10,0),(-5,9),(0,9)],
mpath.Path.MOVETO,mpath.Path.CURVE3,mpath.Path.CURVE3]),**kw)
plt.gca().add_patch(Arrow)
```

After running that code, I don't get the expected result : Even though my arrow is curved and actually starts from (-10,0) to end at (0,9), it doesn't go through (-5,9).

Here's what I get: https://i.stack.imgur.com/3DaW2.png

[image]

I would like to know if there's a way to solve this with that library, or if I have to use another one to get what I want.

On another note, I'd also like to be able to plot a curved arrow which would, after going through a point, go back to the exact start point (for example, an "elliptic"-like arrow going from the (0,0) point, going to (2,2) and come back to (0,0). )

Thank you in advance for your help !

Comment: `(-5,9)` is the control point of the Bezier curve. If you want to have a curve go *through* that point, you need another control point in between.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Now I get exactly what I wanted.